# How can I parse broken XML files in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I'm receiving XML files from an external source over which I have no control. Some of the XML files are broken. Specifically, towards the end of the file, some closing tags are missing. It goes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c/>
</a>
```

I think our system will be fine if we simply ignore the elements that don't have a matching closing tag.

What library can I use to parse what I can from such XML files?

Comment: Do you have a schema for the documents?  It seems like that could make a difference on how easy it is to recover from errors...

Comment: There are parsing techniques that can recover from such errors in various ways. But I do not know what might be available for XML. And I doubt you want to develop that yourself.

Comment: Using StAX seems to do the trick

Comment: What would you do if someone sent you broken Javascript? What do you do if there's a fly in your soup? Complain to the supplier, please, or things will never get better.

Comment: And...another question gets marks as a duplicate, when it isn't actually a duplicate. sigh.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually parse it yourself, no XML parser will work on XML that's not well formed.  One possibility is to use a SAX parser, it will parse the document up to the error then stop.

Answer (score 0):

An XML parser should not support this kind of behavior. But if you can identify whats wrong with the file you could react, clean it up and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if JSoup would work.  It's supposed to be forgiving for HTML.  Idk about XML.